# Cannot use local variable 'hitInfo' before it is declared

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After Updating my project to the latest version of unity3d i got this error 
"error CS0841: Cannot use local variable 'hitInfo' before it is declared
"

`if (Physics.Linecast(head.position, vector, out hitInfo, sphereSensor.obstacleLayer) && Physics.Linecast(head.position, vector2, out hitInfo, sphereSensor.obstacleLayer) && Physics.Linecast(head.position, colliderTarget.bounds.center, out RaycastHit hitInfo, sphereSensor.obstacleLayer))`

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Just wondering: How many times does the hitInfo gets updated? By which call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare (`Type variableName`) earlier in your condition because they are evaluated from left to right, and then, on the first condition (`Physics.Linecast(head.position, vector, out hitInfo, sphereSensor.obstacleLayer)`) the variable `hitInfo` doesn't exist yet.

Change your code to this :

```
// Notice this ---------------------------------v--------v
if (Physics.Linecast(head.position, vector, out RaycastHit hitInfo, sphereSensor.obstacleLayer)
 && Physics.Linecast(head.position, vector2, out hitInfo, sphereSensor.obstacleLayer)
 && Physics.Linecast(head.position, colliderTarget.bounds.center, out hitInfo, sphereSensor.obstacleLayer))
// Type was removed there -------------------------------------------^
```

Or declare the variable before :

```
RaycastHit hitInfo;

if (Physics.Linecast(head.position, vector, out hitInfo, sphereSensor.obstacleLayer)
 && Physics.Linecast(head.position, vector2, out hitInfo, sphereSensor.obstacleLayer)
 && Physics.Linecast(head.position, colliderTarget.bounds.center, out hitInfo, sphereSensor.obstacleLayer))
```

Comment: you are right @Cid thanks did not i did not notice. it Fixed now. thank you

Comment: FYI there will be changes when C#7 is introduced. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/out-variables-in-c-sharp-7-0/